# prevent x:out from stripping elements within selected node

Tags: xml, xpath, jstl

Given the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
     <head>
         <title>Introduction</title>
         <section>section</section>
         <channel>testing/test</channel>
     </head>
     <body>
         <h1>Heading</h1>
         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
         <p>Donec sed enim.</p>
     </body>
</doc>
```

and the following JSTL fragment where the xml has been loaded into the variable 'file':

```
<x:parse var="xml" doc="${file}"/>
<x:out select="$xml//body"/>
```

I am hoping to get:

```
<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Donec sed enim.</p>
```

But am getting:

```
Heading Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Donec sed enim.
```

Notice, no tags. How would I go about getting JSTL to leave the tags in the result?

Comment: The content of this question was adapted from a question on a mailing list that was never answered. The original question is here: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.taglibs.user/6801

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x:out` is very similar to `xsl:value-of` in that it will only select text nodes. Therefore if you want to preserve the XML structure then I would suggest using `x:transform` and writing a stylesheet that will use a `xsl:copy-of` to preserve tags. Another option is to write your own tag :-).